# Python: list of distinct, empty sets

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and am attempting to write code for sieve of Eratosthenes. For this I have to initialize a list of empty sets. I tried doing this `factors=[set()]*1001`, but this produces a shallow copy. I want a deep copy, so that `factors[i]` and `factors[j]` point to different sets. Is there a simple syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
factors = [set() for index in xrange(1001)]
```

Comment: Small note: you can use `_` as a placeholder variable name instead of `index`, if you aren't going to use it. And in python 3, `range` should be used instead of `xrange`.

Answer (score 8):

Same as always.

```
factors = [set() for x in range(1001)]
```

Comment: @BiGYaN if this answer is helpful then it would be nice if you mark it as _right answer_.

Comment: xrange() is better than range() for this kind of large iteration space. So I accepted Michael Hoffman's answer.

Comment: In Python 3, range() is again the best solution

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the standard way of doing it.

```
factors = [set() for x in xrange(1001)]
```

It's better to use [xrange()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of [range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) because xrange() is a generator.

Comment: In Python 3, `range()` is a generator so you can use that instead.