# Repeat a list within a list X number of times

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm working on a project and I need to repeat a list within a list a certain number of times. Obviously, `L.append(L)` just adds the elements again without creating separate lists. I'm just stumped on how to make the lists separate within the big list.

In short form, this is what I have:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If I wanted to to repeat it, say, 3 times so I'd have:

```
L = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

How do I achieve this? I'm looking for lists within the big list.

Comment: As a side note, that's not that `L.append(L)` does. Try it out and see; you'll be surprised by what it does (and it's worth understanding).

Comment: @abarnert Wow, I never knew about that. Is that just what is executed when an infinite loop is found or something?

Comment: It just adds a copy of `L` itself as the last element of `L`. There's nothing necessarily infinite about it… But if you try to, say, flatten it out, or walk it like a tree, _that_ will give you an infinite loop. (If you think about it, printing out a list means walking it like a tree… but Python is smart enough to check for that when printing out a list, so you get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]` instead of an infinite wall of text.)

Comment: @Haidro: Anyway, this is really the same as `mylist[0]` and `mylist[1]` being references to the same thing, as you explained in your answer. It's just that `L` and `L[5]` are references to the same thing.

Comment: Similar questions: [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python), [Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python), [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times), [Best way to extend a list with itself N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560385/best-way-to-extend-a-list-with-itself-n-times).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for any functions:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [L]*3
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

However, you should note that if you change one value in any of the lists, all the others will change because they reference the same object.

```
>>> mylist = [L]*3
>>> mylist[0][0] = 6
>>> print mylist
[[6, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> print L
[6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To avoid this:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mylist = [L[:] for _ in range(3)]
>>> mylist[0][0] = 6
>>> print L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print mylist
[[6, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Notice how `L` didn't change, and only the first list in `mylist` changed.

Thanks everyone in the comments for helping :).