# Repeat list to max number of elements

Tags: python

What is the most efficient method to repeat a list up to a max element length?

To take this:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
max_length = 7
```

And produce this:

```
final_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one']
```

---

<sub>See also [How to replicate array to specific length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127810) for Numpy-specific methods.</sub>

<sub>See also [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381) for lazy iteration over such data.</sub>

Comment: I un-duped this because slicing an `itertools.cycle` is only one way to solve the problem. Creating a definite list of data is different from being able to iterate over the data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd probably use `iterools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(islice(cycle(lst), 7))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 11):

Multiply appropriately?

```
>>> lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> max_length = 7
>>> 
>>> q, r = divmod(max_length, len(lst))
>>> q * lst + lst[:r]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one']
```

Benchmarked mine and mgilson's solution, mine looks more efficient, for example for the below test mine takes about 0.7 seconds while mgilson's takes about 2.8 seconds.

```
from timeit import timeit
data = "lst = ['one', 'two', 'three'] * 1000; max_length = 12345678"

print(timeit('q, r = divmod(max_length, len(lst)); q * lst + lst[:r]',
             data,
             number=10))

print(timeit('list(islice(cycle(lst), max_length))',
             data + '; from itertools import cycle, islice',
             number=10))
```