# How to replicate array to specific length array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, replication

I want replicate a small array to specific length array

Example:

```
var = [22,33,44,55] # ==> len(var) = 4
n = 13
```

The new array that I want would be:

```
var_new = [22,33,44,55,22,33,44,55,22,33,44,55,22]
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
var = [22,33,44,55]
di = np.arange(13)
var_new = np.empty(13)
var_new[di] = var
```

I get error message:

> DeprecationWarning: assignment will raise an error in the future, most likely because your index result shape does not match the value array shape. You can use `arr.flat[index] = values` to keep the old behaviour.

But I get my corresponding variable:

```
var_new
array([ 22.,  33.,  44.,  55.,  22.,  33.,  44.,  55.,  22.,  33.,  44.,
    55.,  22.])
```

So, how to solve the error? Is there an alternative?

---

<sub>See also [Repeat list to max number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863250) for general methods not specific to Numpy.</sub>

<sub>See also [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381) for lazy iteration over such data.</sub>

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are better ways to replicate the array, for example you could simply use [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

> Return a new array with the specified shape.
>
> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of `a`. [...]

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> var = [22,33,44,55]
>>> n = 13
>>> np.resize(var, n)
array([22, 33, 44, 55, 22, 33, 44, 55, 22, 33, 44, 55, 22])
```

Comment: This is unusual, a request that actually matches `np.resize`!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't get an error, but a warning, that `var_new[di] = var` is deprecated if `var_new[di]` has dimensions that do not match `var`.

Second, the error message tells what to do: use

```
var_new[di].flat = var
```

and you do not get a warning any more and it is guaranteed to work.

---

Another, easy way to do this if `numpy` is not needed is to just use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> var = [22, 33, 44, 55]
>>> list(it.islice(it.cycle(var), 13))
[22, 33, 44, 55, 22, 33, 44, 55, 22, 33, 44, 55, 22]
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the array (called lists in python) with [:] because they are mutable. The python short cut is then just to multiply the copy and add one more
element.

```
>>> var = [22, 33, 44, 55]
>>> n = 3
>>> newlist = var[:]*n + var[:1]
```

gives the 13 elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var = [22,33,44,55]
n = 13
```

Repeating a list (or any other iterable) can be done without `numpy`, using `itertools`'s `cycle()` and `islice()` functions

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
var_new = list(islice(cycle(var),0,n)
```

Comment: This make a list of 13 lists