# Circular batch generation from list

Tags: python, generator

Basically, I would like to create an infinite generator from the given list `l` with some batch size of `batch_size`. For example, if I have list of `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `batch_size = 2`, I'd like to generate infinite loop of `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`, `[5, 1]`, `[2, 3]`, ... (similar to [itertool.circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python) with additional batch size)

My current approach is the following which doesn't give the right solution yet because at the end I just pad the first element of list when I reach the end:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def generator(l, batch_size=2):
    while 1:
        for i in range(0, len(l), batch_size):
            batch = l[i:(i + batch_size)]
            if len(batch) < batch_size:
                batch.extend(l[0: batch_size - len(batch)])
            yield batch

>> gen = generator(l, batch_size=2)
>> next(gen) # [1, 2]
>> next(gen) # [3, 4]
>> next(gen) # [5, 1]
>> next(gen) # [1, 2] << want [2, 3] instead
```

Is there a way to do that in a circular way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you basically want a combination of "take" and `cycle`:

```
>>> def circle_batch(iterable, batchsize):
...     it = itertools.cycle(iterable)
...     while True:
...         yield list(itertools.islice(it, batchsize))
...
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c = circle_batch(l, 2)
>>> next(c)
[1, 2]
>>> next(c)
[3, 4]
>>> next(c)
[5, 1]
>>> next(c)
[2, 3]
>>> next(c)
[4, 5]
```

From the [recipes in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) you'll see that `take` is a basic tool, so using that:

```
>>> def take(n, iterable):
...     "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
...     return list(islice(iterable, n))
...
>>> def cycle_batch(iterable, batchsize):
...     it = itertools.cycle(iterable)
...     while True:
...         return take(batchsize, it)
...
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c = circle_batch(l, 2)
>>> next(c)
[1, 2]
>>> next(c)
[3, 4]
>>> next(c)
[5, 1]
>>> next(c)
[2, 3]
>>> next(c)
[4, 5]
>>> next(c)
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! This work perfectly (it has to be 5 mins before accepting the solution).

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
def generator(l, batch_size=2):
    gen = iter(itertools.cycle(l))
    while 1:
        yield [next(gen) for _ in range(batch_size)]

gen = generator(l, batch_size=2)
```

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl! This works great. I have to accept @juanpa.arrivillaga tho but both solutions work for me :)

Comment: maybe you meant to type `cycle` not `circle`?