# Sorted list gone empty when statistics.median (Python) applied on it

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to use the Python statistics library but have trouble with `median`. As you can see below, the program return the `mean`, but the list somehow becomes empty for `median` and raises error. Please take a look, and thanks in advance!

```
import statistics

RawInput = input("Please enter a list separated by commas\n")
lst = RawInput.split(", ")
usable_lst = map(int, lst)


def mean():
    print("The mean is " + str(statistics.mean(usable_lst)))


def median():
    Sorted = sorted(usable_lst)
    print("The median is" + str(statistics.median(Sorted)))
    print("The median low is" + str(statistics.median_low(Sorted)))
    print("The median high is" + str(statistics.median_high(Sorted)))


def mode():
    print("The mode is" + str(statistics.mode(usable_lst)))


mean()
median()
mode()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the probelm is that `usable_lst` is a generator, and once you access it in the `mean()` function you empty it.

A fix can be to change `usable_lst = map(int, lst)` to `usable_lst = list(map(int, last))`

You can refer to the following links that might shed more light on the issue you are encountering:

[Why can a python generator only be used once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032155/why-can-a-python-generator-only-be-used-once)

[Resetting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python)

[How to make a repeating generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376438/how-to-make-a-repeating-generator-in-python)