# How to select a value as ordered in list each time script runs?

Tags: python, list

I currently have this in my Python script which is scheduled to run every 30s:

```
import random 
myList = ["12345", "123456", "1234567", "12345678"]
mySelection = random.choice(myList)
```

However, I'm looking for a solution that will select item from the list not randomly but in an order of the list items each time script runs (each 30s). For example:

- my.py runs for the first time and `mySelection` = "12345"
- my.py runs for the second time and `mySelection` = "123456"
- my.py runs for the third time and `mySelection` = "1234567"
- my.py runs for the fourth time and `mySelection` = "12345678"
- my.py runs for the fifth time and `mySelection` = "12345" - this is
  when it starts over from the beginning of the list.
- and so on...

Could someone help with this?

Comment: similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416381/9144250)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to simply save the variable or index of the next wanted `mySelection` in a file and once you have read the value, you increment it by 1 and save the file again. This could be done with a simple text file or for example using the Pickle module if you want to be able to save more complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from itertools import cycle
cycled_list = cycle(myList)

# every time you call next(cycled_list)
# you get elements from it
next(cycled_list)  # '12345'
next(cycled_list)  # '123456'
next(cycled_list)  # '1234567'
next(cycled_list)  # '12345678'
next(cycled_list)  # '12345'  # cycling iteration
```

Comment: Thanks! However it prints this instead of the actual list value `<itertools.cycle object at 0x10add80a0> ` would you know how can i solve this? thx

Comment: @Baobab1988 if you print the `cycled_list `it would print that. However printing the `print(next(cycled_list))` returns actual result.