# How to make a list start-end connected?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
l = [0, 1, 2]
```

and obviously `l[0] = 0`, `l[1] = 1`, `l[2] = 2`,
but I want `l[3]` to be = to `0`, `l[4] = 1`, `l[5] = 2` and so on...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need to access the non-existing indexes directly, or you want to iterate over the list indefinitely? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416381/476…

Comment: l = l*n ? n for how many times you want to repeat.

Comment: Perhaps `l[5 % len(l)]`…?

Comment: What problem do you hope to solve by doing this? The best approach depends on why you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the modulus operator to cycle through the elements of the list.

```
l[index % 3]
```

In general:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2]

lst[index % len(lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can "multiply" a list to create a longer, repeating list of the original. Alternatively, you can create an iterator that just yields the same sequence of numbers indefinitely:

```
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2] * 5
>>> numbers
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> number_iter = cycle([0, 1, 2])
>>> next(number_iter)
0
>>> next(number_iter)
1
>>> next(number_iter)
2
>>> next(number_iter)
0
>>> next(number_iter)
1
>>> next(number_iter)
2
>>>
```