# Iterate through small list n times

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops

What i have:

```py
   list_1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
   rounds = 5
```

What i need: get elements of a small list one at a time, for `n` times; considering that the length of the list is smaller than `n`:

```py
   for _ in range(rounds):
      -> get element of list_1 sequentially
```

Expected result:

```
   "a"
   "b"
   "c"
   "a"
   "b"
```

obs: numpy approaches are acceptable.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch as many values as you want from `itertools.cycle` iterator:

```
import itertools
list_1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
rounds = 5
i = itertools.cycle(list_1)
print([next(i) for _ in range(rounds)])
```

gives

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

Of course, you don't have to build a list - here is a `for` loop (using the above iterator):

```
for _ in range(rounds):
    print(next(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your task based solely on *Numpy* functions,
without support from e.g. *itertools*.

Run your loop as:

```
for tt in np.resize(list_1, rounds):
    print(tt)
```

Or if you need the whole list in one go, run:

```
result = np.resize(list_1, rounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any Python module for this, just the modulo `%` operator to return to the first element after you pass the last one:

```
list_1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
rounds = 5

for i in range(rounds):
    print(list_1[i % len(list_1)])
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
a
b
```

You can also assign `len(list_1)` to a variable e.g. `length`, so that you won't have to calculate the length in each iteration.