# Best way to extend a list with itself N times

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, mutable

So I have a list `[a,b,c]` and I want to obtain `[a,b,c,a,b,c,...a,b,c]`.

I can of course do this with two nested loops, but there must be a better way? `itertools.cycle()` would have been solution if I could provide a count.

Two constraints:

1. it should work in 2.7 (but for the sake of curiosity I'm interested in a 3.x solution)
2. list elements should be independent copies (they are mutable types)

Comment: @`itertools.cycle()` won't make copies of the elements. "Better" is meaningless without any comparison criteria.

Comment: Related questions: [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416381/7851470), [Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3459098/7851470), [Repeat a list within a list X number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16095865/7851470), [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225072/7851470).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually I came up with:

```
[copy.copy(e) for _ in range(N) for e in sourceList]
```

Comment: yeah, it's probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 4):

For immutable types, you can use multiplication operator on the list:

```
>>> [1,2,3]*5
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

for mutable types, you need to perform a copy of the elements prior to inserting.

I would chain a repeated copy of the items of the list.

```
import copy,itertools

a=[12]
b=[13]
c=[14]

l = [a,b,c]

new_l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(copy.copy,l) for _ in range(5)))
```

in `new_l`, all lists are independent (references are not copies from each other). You may need `copy.deepcopy` in some cases.

Comment: You got me thinking... and I came up with something I find better. comment on either answer if you think I'm wrong :)

Comment: According to timeit, very little difference in execution times between your answer and mine (1.5% difference).

Comment: but your answer takes 50% less time to understand because it's really simpler :)

Answer (score -1):

To start with, if one has a `list = [a, b, c]`, if one prints it, one will get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-eb02c90df247> in <module>
----> 1 list = [a, b, c]
      2 list

NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

The `list` should be defined as follows

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(list)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

For your case, simply multiplying the list with N will do the work. For the examples, let's consider N=3

```
>>> n = 3
>>> list = list*n
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now, and giving an alternative answer, as the need may arise, if one wants to extend the list (considering, for the example, N=3) as follows

```
['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'c']
```

One can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) do that

```
>>> n = 3
>>> list= np.repeat(list, n)
array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

This retrieved an array. If that doesn't fit one's needs and one wants a list (use [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)), as follows

```
>>> list = list.tolist()
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: 1) consider that a,b,and c are variables referencing mutable objects. 2) the resulting list hasn't got independent elements, if I modify one this also modifies the "copies".