# Repeating list in python N times?

Tags: python

I have a list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and I want to repeat a list `n` times.
For example, if `n = 2` I want `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` as output.

Is there any inbuilt solution in python except `append` and `for` loop because value of `n` might go up to 1000 too ?

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826126/7109869) may be of help.

Answer (score 10):

Python allows multiplication of lists:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 2
print(my_list*n)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Note that this will copy objects by reference, so may lead to some very difficult to find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If the generated list is large, it can be better to use a generator, so that items are generated one at a time on the fly without creating the whole large list in memory:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle


def repeat(lst, times):
    return islice(cycle(lst), len(lst)*times)

lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in repeat(lst, 3):
    print(item, end=' ')

#0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

You can still create a list if you want:

```
print(list(repeat(lst, 3)))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How it works: [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will cycle on `lst` indefinitely, and we keep only the `len(lst) * times` first items using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiplication

```py
[1,2,3] * 3
# [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve it.

```
arr1=[1,2]
n=2
arr2=arr1*n #number of times you want to repeat
print(arr2)
```

**Output:**

> [1,2,1,2]