# Multiple duplication when using copy.deepcopy() on lxml tree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, deep-copy

Suppose I have an original lxml tree as following:

`my_data.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:liechtenstein:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <holidays>
      <christmas>Yes</christmas>
    </holidays>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
    <malay>
      <holidays>
        <ramadan>Yes</ramadan>
      </holidays>
    </malay>
  </ethnicity>
</data>
```

Parsing:

```
xt = etree.parse("my_data.xml")
xr = xt.getroot()
```

Now I want to create a list of duplicated trees. In this example, I create a list of 3 duplicated trees:

```
f_list = [1, 2, 3]

xtrees = [copy.deepcopy(xt)] * len(f_list)
xroots = [xtree.getroot() for xtree in xtrees]
ramadan_nodes = [xtree.find('.//{*}ramadan') for xtree in xtrees]
```

Along with those 3 trees, I have a list of `ramadan` nodes, each of which belongs to individual tree.
Now I want to duplicate the `ramadan` node in each of those new 3 trees, and append it to them, individually.

```
for i in range(3):
    new_ramadan_node = copy.deepcopy(ramadan_nodes[i])
    ramadan_parent = ramadan_nodes[i].getparent()
    position = ramadan_parent.index(ramadan_nodes[i]) + 1
    ramadan_parent.insert(position, new_ramadan_node)
```

As above, I intend to have only ONE duplicated `ramadan` node in each tree. However, upon running that code, each of the 3 duplicated trees contains FOUR `ramadan` nodes (1 being the original and 3 being added by the `for` loop above).

Why is this happening? Also, I notice that if I want to print the list `ramadan` nodes with:

```
print(ramadan_nodes)
```

I get these numbers `Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee}ramadan at 0x203b4f849c0>` repeated exactly 3 times as following:

```
[<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee}ramadan at 0x203b4f849c0>, 
<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee}ramadan at 0x203b4f849c0>, 
<Element {aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee}ramadan at 0x203b4f849c0>]
```

What is this number `0x203b4f849c0`? I suspect it has something to do with the multiple duplication here. If someone could help explaining. Thanks.

Below is the full continuous code:

```
import copy
import lxml.etree as etree

file_path = "my_data.xml"
xt = etree.parse(file_path)
xr = xt.getroot()

f_list = [1, 2, 3]

xtrees = [copy.deepcopy(xt)] * len(f_list)
xroots = [xtree.getroot() for xtree in xtrees]
ramadan_nodes = [xtree.find('.//{*}ramadan') for xtree in xtrees]

for i in range(3):
    new_ramadan_node = copy.deepcopy(ramadan_nodes[i])
    ramadan_parent = ramadan_nodes[i].getparent()
    position = ramadan_parent.index(ramadan_nodes[i]) + 1
    ramadan_parent.insert(position, new_ramadan_node)

print(ramadan_nodes)
etree.dump(xroots[0])
etree.dump(xroots[1])
etree.dump(xroots[2])
```

***Update***:

If I replace these two lines :

```
xtrees = [copy.deepcopy(xt)] * len(f_list)
xroots = [xtree.getroot() for xtree in xtrees]
```

with

```
xtrees = []
xroots = []
xtrees.append(copy.deepcopy(xt))
xroots.append(xtrees[-1].getroot())
xtrees.append(copy.deepcopy(xt))
xroots.append(xtrees[-1].getroot())
xtrees.append(copy.deepcopy(xt))
xroots.append(xtrees[-1].getroot())
```

I get the expected output. It seems `copy.deepcopy` does not produce distinct objects when used in a `list`? Why is it so?

Comment: The number is the "identity" of the element, as returned by `id()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id.

Comment: It is easier to help if you provide a single piece of complete code (including `import` statements) that we can copy, paste and run. Here you have posted fragments that have to be patched together.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks. I updated with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `*` operator:

```
xtrees = [copy.deepcopy(xt)] * len(f_list)
```

This does not create copies; it creates references to the original `xt` object.

To get actual copies, you can do as follows:

```
xtrees = [copy.deepcopy(xt) for _ in range(len(f_list))]
```

Related information:

- https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list
- [Repeat a list within a list X number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16095865/407651)