# Creating list of individual list items multiplied n times

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, emcee

I'm fairly new to Python, and think this should be a fairly common problem, but can't find a solution. I've already looked at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python) and found it helpful for one item, but I'm struggling to extend the example to multiple items without using a 'for' loop. I'm running this bit of code for 250 walkers through Emcee, so I'm looking for the fastest way possible.

I have a list of numbers, `a = [x,y,z]` that I want to repeat `b = [1,2,3]` times (for example), so I end up with a list of lists:

```
[
 [x],
 [y,y],
 [z,z,z]
]
```

The 'for' loop I have is:

```
c = [ ]
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    c.append([a[i]]*b[i])
```

Which does exactly what I want, but means my code is excruciatingly slow. I've also tried naively turning a and b into arrays and doing `[a]*b` in the hopes that it would multiply element by element, but no joy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `zip`  and a list comprehension here:

```
>>> a = ['x','y','z']
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> [[x]*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[['x'], ['y', 'y'], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

or:

```
>>> [[x for _ in xrange(y)] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[['x'], ['y', 'y'], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

`zip` will create the whole list in memory first, to get an iterator use `itertools.izip`

In case `a` contains mutable objects like lists or lists of lists, then you may have to use `copy.deepcopy` here because modifying one copy will change other copies as well.:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy as dc
>>> a = [[1 ,4],[2, 5],[3, 6, 9]]
>>> f = [[dc(x) for _ in xrange(y)] for x,y in zip(a,b)]

#now all objects are unique
>>> [[id(z) for z in x] for x in f]
[[172880236], [172880268, 172880364], [172880332, 172880492, 172880428]]
```

`timeit` comparisons(ignoring imports):

```
>>> a = ['x','y','z']*10**4
>>> b = [100,200,300]*10**4

>>> %timeit [[x]*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
1 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop

>>> %timeit [[x]*y for x,y in izip(a,b)]
1 loops, best of 3: 98.8 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(lambda v: [v[0]]*v[1], zip(a,b))
1 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(list, map(repeat, a, b))
1 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(list, imap(repeat, a, b))
1 loops, best of 3: 211 ms per loop

>>> %timeit map(mul, [[x] for x in a], b)
1 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

>>> %timeit [[x for _ in xrange(y)] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
1 loops, best of 3: 645 ms per loop

>>> %timeit [[x for _ in xrange(y)] for x,y in izip(a,b)]
1 loops, best of 3: 680 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning `itertools.izip`.

Comment: Thanks! Will the 'for' loops still slow the code down, though?

Comment: @user2444731 what do you mean “slow”? Why do you think that `for`-loop is slow? Slow compared to what?

Comment: Since user is new, it's probably wise to point out that [x]*y creates y references to x, which can be problematic in some cases. As if one is changed, it is possible for all of them to be changed.

Comment: As Nuclearman says, I'm new - I was told that `for`-loops are intrinsically slow, and that they're best avoided for MCMC - still blindly following any advice I hear :s

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that this was for a Monte Carlo algorithm when you posed the question. Context is helpful.

Comment: @user2444731 List comprehensions are slightly faster than normal for-loops, I don't think you can get any faster than this in pure python.

Comment: @Nuclearman Yes, but note that `[[x for _ in range(y)] for x,y in zip(a,b)]` is perfectly equivalent to the `[x] * y` variant(apart from being much slower, since `[x] * y` is an operation completely done at C level, while the list-comprehension is a python loop however optimized).
@user2444731 Do not fall in premature optimization! Always write the code in the simplest and more readable way, then, *after profiling*, find the bottlenecks and optimize the code.

Comment: @Bakuriu: True, I brought it up [x] * y since the issue can't be avoided in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to do it is with [*map()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and [*operator.mul()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> map(mul, [['x'], ['y'], ['z']], [1, 2, 3])
[['x'], ['y', 'y'], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

Comment: +1 I just figured this out when you posted it (the input is not a list of lists however)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> a = ['x','y','z']
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> starmap(repeat,zip(a,b))
```

`starmap` returns an iterable which contains values equal to the result of calling `repeat` with arguments equal to the values contained in a tuple, in this case for example `('x',1)`.

```
>>> for p in starmap(repeat,zip(a,b)):
    print(list(p))


['x']
['y', 'y']
['z', 'z', 'z']
```

Comment: note that you have to call `map(list, ...)` on the `starmap` to get the list of lists

Answer (score 2):

@kirelagin suggested a version without `for` loops, here's one that also doesn't have `lambda`s (Keep in mind the solution by @AshwiniChaudhary is most readable)

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> a = ['x','y','z']
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> map(list, map(repeat, a, b))
[['x'], ['y', 'y'], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

---

```
>>> map(repeat, a, b)
[repeat('x', 1), repeat('y', 2), repeat('z', 3)]
```

creates a list of `repeat` objects (use `imap` on Python 2.x if you want a lazy iterator instead of a list) which don't take up any extra space in memory, these are great if you just want to iterate over the items instead of store them)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version without `for` loops if you don't like them for some reason:

```
map(lambda v: [v[0]]*v[1], zip(a,b))
```

I should also warn you that this version is slightly slower than a list comprehension:

```
$ a = ['hi']*100
$ b = [20]*100

$ %timeit map(lambda v: [v[0]]*v[1], zip(a,b))
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 us per loop

%timeit [[x]*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.1 us per loop
```

I'd also recommend using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` if you are on Python 2.