# Using for loops to create multiple lists with identical elements

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I have a function.

```
def createj(n): 
    output = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        output.append(range(1,i+1))
    return output
```

Presently, when I print createj(2) it gives me [[], [1], [1,2,3]]. I want it to return [[1],[2,2]] or when i print createj(4); it prints [[1], [2,2], [3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]. I know I must use a for loop but there is clearly a large error in my for loop which keep making mistakes on. Thanks!

Comment: This question is asked several times by the same user


Answer (score 2):

Alter your append line

```
output.append([i] * i)
```

Comment: That brings me very close! @Vorsprung However, that produces [[],[1],[2,2]]. However, how would I about changing it so it produces [[1],[2,2]?

Comment: Your range needs to be between (1,n+1). Right now the first value is 0, so when it multiplies it appends nothing. Take a look at my answer @user3000645

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I've been using range incorrectly @samrap

Comment: like samrap says the for loop range has to be adjusted as well to range(1,n+1)

Answer (score 2):

It's good to use list comprehension.

```
output = [[i] * i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
```

See [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
def create(n):
    output = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        output.append([i] * i)
    return output
```

You need to set the amount of times to append the item to the list. Multiply it by the current value of the range. Also, make your range between 1 and n+1, otherwise the first value will be a 0 and will give you an empty list during the first iteration.

You also might want to try `xrange` instead of `range` if you are going to be putting large values into the function. `range` generates a list whereas `xrange` does not, so it is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
output = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    output.append([n] * n)
```

what `[x] * y` is create a list of size `y` with `x` elements