# Why is the use of [e] * n (for creating a list of single item repeated n times) fast in Python?

Tags: python, list

Following up from:
[Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

```
python -m timeit '[0.5]*100000'
1000 loops, best of 3: 382 usec per loop

python -m timeit '[0.5 for i in range(100000)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.07 msec per loop
```

Obviously, the second one is slower due to range(). I am not aware why [e] * n is so fast (or how it's implemented internally in Python).

Comment: Because in CPython allocating and copying a PyObject* is fast in C? I'm not sure what kind of answer you're after...?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have made a few edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dis.dis](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) lets you look at the operations Python performs when evaluating each expression:

```
In [57]: dis.dis(lambda: [0.5]*100000)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0.5)
              3 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (100000)
              9 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             10 RETURN_VALUE        

In [58]: dis.dis(lambda: [0.5 for i in range(100000)])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (0.5)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 RETURN_VALUE
```

The list comprehension is performing a loop, loading the constant `0.5` each time, and appending it to a result list.

The expression `[0.5]*100000` requires only one [BINARY_MULTIPLY](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_MULTIPLY).

---

Also note that `[obj]*N` makes a list of length `N`, with `N` reference to the exact same `obj`.

The list comprehension `[expr for i in range(N)]` *evaluates* `expr` `N` times -- even if `expr` evaluates to the same value each time.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to what @unutbu said, `BINARY_MULTIPLY` ends up executing this tight loop in [listobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ae9b74c2b357/Objects/listobject.c#l529):

```
if (Py_SIZE(a) == 1) {
    elem = a->ob_item[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        items[i] = elem;
        Py_INCREF(elem);
    }
    return (PyObject *) np;
}
```

This is pretty self-explanatory: it makes a bunch of references to the same object in a tight C loop.  Thus nearly 100% of `[obj] * N` executes in native code, meaning it goes *really* fast.

Standard caveats about doing this with mutable objects apply (ie: don't do it with mutable objects), since you make a boatload of references to the same object.