# Passing a class instance method to another function in Python (2.7)

Tags: python

sorry if the title does not make sense, I am relatively new to this. This is my code:

```
class MeanFlow:
    def __init__(self, V0=1):
        self.V0 = V0
    def LHS(self, t, y):
        return y[0]*self.V0


def velocity_field(w,f):
    z = 0 # dummy 
    u = f(z,w).real
    v = -1*f(z,w).imag 
    return u, v

w0 = 1
mean = MeanFlow()
dwdz = mean.LHS
print(velocity_field(w0, dwdz))
```

But I get the error `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

My question is how do I pass this function which is a method of my class instance into another function. If I define the function outside the class and pass it to another function this works but is not what I want. Thanks!

**Edit:** The typo `return = y[0]*self.V0` has been corrected.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't demonstrate the error you've posted. Instead, it fails to compile due to the line `return = y[0]*self.V0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's generating `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` is this:

```
y[0]
```

This is because at this point, `y`'s value is `1`, an integer, and `y[0]` is acting as if `y` is a list or string (`__getitem__` is the method called to get items in lists). If `y` were a list (e.g. `y = [1]`), it'd work fine.

If you remove the `[0]`, you're in business:

```
class MeanFlow:
    def __init__(self, V0=1):
        self.V0 = V0
    def LHS(self, t, y):
        return y*self.V0


def velocity_field(w,f):
    z = 0 # dummy 
    u = f(z,w).real
    v = -1*f(z,w).imag 
    return u, v

w0 = 1
mean = MeanFlow()
dwdz = mean.LHS
print(velocity_field(w0, dwdz))
```

Comment: Sorry, the assignment to return was completely wrong of me, I didn't spot that. And thanks for the kind response :)

Comment: No problem! Mistakes like that are very hard to spot, especially when you've written the code yourself. Often my solution is to take a step back and imagine what the values of the variable *should* be in theory at each point along the way, then use `print` to find what they *actually* are.

Comment: As a followup I am wondering why it is not possible to then define w0 = [1] and use the method involving y[0]?

Comment: Sure - that'll work if we go back to `y[0]`, so `return y[0]*self.V0`. However, if you set `w0=[1]` and then use `return y*self.V0`, you'll end up doing this: `[1] * 1`, which returns `[1]` (see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)), and `.real` is a property of [numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html), not `lists`

Comment: @l4mpi I appreciate your input, i'm still getting the hang of programming and you are right I should have tested that the variables actually were what I meant them to be. I am not used to the error messages that python throws and so I assumed the error was due to something entirely different. Ill try to improve in the future!

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your code.
You are passing `1` as the first argument to `velocity_field` which in turn passes it to `LHS` as the second argument (`y`). Lastly, you call `__getitem__` on `y` by doing `y[0]`, and that raises the exception.

Moreover, there is a syntax error as you assign the result to `return`.