# in python how to repeat an item N time into a list?

Tags: python

say, i have a string A='baby', want to repeat A 4 times to generate a list looks like this:

```
['baby', 'baby', 'baby', 'baby']
```

my current solution is :

```
((A+".")*4).split('.')[:-1]
```

however, this looks really awkward.

is there any more civilized solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update*** *This answer is expanded with more examples on the canonical question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557558/541136*

You can do it like this:

```
['baby'] * 4
```

Note that this is best only used with immutable items in the list, because they all point to the same place in memory. I use this frequently when I have to build a table with a schema of all strings.

```
schema = ['string'] * len(columns)
```

---

Beware doing this with mutable objects, when you change one of them, they all change because they're all the *same* object:

```
foo = [[]] *4
foo[0].append('x')
```

foo now returns:

```
[['x'], ['x'], ['x'], ['x']]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using list comprehension:

`['baby' for x in range(4)]`

Comment: ['baby' for _ in range(4)]

Comment: list comprehensions aren't the answer for everything

Comment: No, they are not. But they are certainly better than OP's current solution.

Comment: @AaronHall, especially since in this case it's take about 1.5 longer than list multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Build a list with single element and multiply the list

```
['baby']*4
```