# Create n empty strings in one line

Tags: python, python-2.7

Likely a duplicate (sorry). I looked around and couldn't find my answer.

I want to generate a list of `n` empty strings in a one liner.

I've tried:

```
>>> list(str('') * 16)
# ['']
>>> list(str(' ') * 16)
# [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
# anything with a char in it is working
```

The below works, but is there a better way? Why doesn't `list(str('') * 16)` work?

```
>>> [str() for c in 'c' * 16]
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that's more an answer than a comment, no?

Comment: @DSM I was looking for a dup, I think this one is good enough: [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Maybe. I would've gotten lost in the length/complexity of that answer.

Comment: you can use   numpy.chararray((size of the string)).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See the [Python standard types page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
>>> [''] * 16
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

> s * n, n * s
>
> n shallow copies of s concatenated

where `s` is a sequence and `n` is an integer.

The full footnote from the docs for this operation:

> Values of n less than 0 are treated as 0 (which yields an empty sequence of the same type as s). Note also that the copies are shallow; nested structures are not copied. This often haunts new Python programmers; consider:

```
>>> lists = [[]] * 3
>>> lists
[[], [], []]
>>> lists[0].append(3)
>>> lists
[[3], [3], [3]]
```

> What has happened is that [[]] is a one-element list containing an empty list, so all three elements of [[]] * 3 are (pointers to) this single empty list. Modifying any of the elements of lists modifies this single list. You can create a list of different lists this way:

```
>>> lists = [[] for i in range(3)]
>>> lists[0].append(3)
>>> lists[1].append(5)
>>> lists[2].append(7)
>>> lists
[[3], [5], [7]]
```

Comment: This drove me insane. Sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can multiply out a list like this. Since `''` is **immutable** you don't need to worry that they are all references to the same string.

```
[''] * 16
```

You can't use the same trick for mutable objects (eg lists or dicts). You need to use something like your last version

```
[mutable_thing() for c in range(16)]
```

or

```
[[] for c in range(16)]
```

or

```
[{} for c in range(16)]
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why this isn't dangerous.