# How to sort a dictionary by a value passed through a function?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda, strptime

I have a dictionary named 'times' which maps keys to string values that represent a time:

```
times = {'key1': '12.23', 'key2': '43:53.29', 'key3': '1:38:11.50r'}
```

The string takes the form of [hours]:[minutes]:[seconds].[milliseconds][r]
where every field is optional.  The r is a flag that doesn't depend on any other values being filled in and doesn't factor into sorting.  [hours] requires that [minutes] and down are present, but [minutes] doesn't require [hours] to be present.

I want to end up with a list of keys sorted by the time-ordering of their values.

I have the following:

```
standings = sorted(times, key=times.__getitem__)
```

but it only sorts based on a string value.  I'm new to python, but if I were using java I would probably write a Time class with a custom compareTo() function to get the sort to work.

I could write a function that converts the string to a time in milliseconds, then sort based on that, but don't know how I would do so using 'key=' in the sorted() function.

Comment: What is `50r` in `'1:38:11.50r'`?

Comment: half a second, in a relay (these are race times).  The 'r' is just a flag that doesn't mean anything for sorting purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
def as_list(time):
    """
    >>> as_list('1:38:11.50r')
    [1, 38, 11, 50]
    >>> as_list('2.23')
    [0, 0, 2, 23]
    """
    # Extract times and convert to integers
    times = [int(x) for x in re.split(r"[:.]", re.sub("[a-z]$", "", time))]
    # If needed pad from the left side with zeros and return
    return times if len(times) == 4 else [0] * (4 - len(times)) + times

[k for k, t in sorted(times.items(), key = lambda x: as_list(x[1]))]
```

Or even more concise way:

```
[key for _, key in sorted((as_list(v), k) for k, v in times.items())]
```

It works because lists or tuples in Python are sorted in a lexicographical order. Let's say you have list as follows:

```
>>> l = [[0, 1], [-1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [0, -1]]
```

You can call `sorted` on it

```
>>> sorted(l)
[[-1, 2, 3], [0, -1], [0, 1], [4, 5]]
```

Hence all the magic.

Regarding `[0] * (4 - len(times)) + times` you can read more here: [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

Long story short `some_list * some_integer` creates a list that contains elements of `some_list` repeated `some_integer` times.

Comment: It looks like this works!  I understand splitting based on ':' and '.', ignoring any non-numeric characters.  Could you explain "return times if len(times) == 4 else [0] * (4 - len(times)) + times" and "[k for k, t in sorted(times.items(), key = lambda x: as_list(x[1]))]"?

Comment: You don't need `\.`, `.` will not have its special meaning with `[]`. Also, use raw strings.

Comment: @thefourtheye Updated, thanks. I've spend to much time with R lately and I feel like I have to escape everything and then escape once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
standings = sorted(times.items(),key = lambda t : t[0])
```

it assumes that you want to sort by the key of the dictionary. If you want to sort by value then replace t[0] with t[1].

Note that I used t[0] to get a reference to the key as an example but in your case you would reference t[1] but you would probably pass this value to a function that will convert the time into a string format that would be easy to sort lexicographically.  For instance, let us assume you have a time_format method that returns a padded time then you would replace the t[0] above with time_format(t[1]).

Comment: that gives me a sorted list of values.  I need a list of keys sorted by a function of their values.

Comment: So {Bob: 2, Jim: 5, Billy: 3} would yield something like [Bob, Billy, Jim]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a function **to_decimal** to convert the time string to a decimal for comparison, then:

```
standings = sorted(times, key = lambda x : to_decimal(times[x]))
```

Comment: how would you convert to decimal?  I'm not sure 1.43.23.43 would work

Comment: I guess you'll need to parse the string to determine the unit of each part and then sum up to a decimal.

Comment: so you mean convert the time into milliseconds and then sort?