# How to have a list with all the same items, but the length be equal to and equation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm wondering how to have a list with all the same items, but the length be equal to and equation, for example:

```
myList = 'a' * 10
```

but this gives you

```
myList = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
```

when I want

```
myList = a, a, a, a, etc.
```

Comment: Your syntax is slighty off: use `['a'] * 10` instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the shortest way:

```
['a']*10
```