# Cannot create dataframe from list: pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list that is generated by a function. when I execute `print` on my list:

```
print(preds_labels)
```

I obtain:

```
[(0.,8.),(0.,13.),(0.,19.),(0.,19.),(0.,19.),(0.,19.),(0.,19.),(0.,20.),(0.,21.),(0.,23.)]
```

but when I want to create a `DataFrame` with this command:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(preds_labels, ["prediction", "label"])
```

I get an error message:

> not supported type: type 'numpy.float64'

If I create the list manually, I have no problem. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pyspark uses its own type system and unfortunately it doesn't deal with numpy well. It works with python types though. So you could manually convert the `numpy.float64` to `float` like

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(float(tup[0]), float(tup[1]) for tup in preds_labels], 
    ["prediction", "label"]
)
```

Note pyspark will then take them as `pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType`

Answer (score 1):

To anyone arriving here with the error:

```
typeerror not supported type class 'numpy.str_'
```

This is true for string as well. So if you created your list strings using numpy , try to change it to pure python.
[Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times)