# Function on each row of pandas DataFrame but not generating a new column

Tags: function, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas as follows:

```
  A    B    C    D
  3    4    3    1
  5    2    2    2
  2    1    4    3
```

My final goal is to produce some constraints for an optimization problem using the information in each row of this data frame so I don't want to generate an output and add it to the data frame. The way that I have done that is as below:

```
def Computation(row):

    App = pd.Series(row['A'])

    App = App.tolist()

    PT = [row['B']] * len(App)

    CS = [row['C']] * len(App)

    DS = [row['D']] * len(App)

    File3 = tuplelist(zip(PT,CS,DS,App))

    return m.addConstr(quicksum(y[r,c,d,a] for r,c,d,a in File3) == 1)
```

But it does not work out by calling:

```
df.apply(Computation, axis = 1)
```

Could you please let me know if there is anyway to do this process?

Comment: m is defined for the interface of python and an optimization software. .iterrows works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.apply` will attempt to convert the value returned by the function to a pandas Series or DataFrame. So, if that is not your goal, you are better off using `.iterrows`:

```
# In pseudocode:
for row in df.iterrows:
    constrained = Computation(row)
```

---

Also, your `Computation` can be expressed as:

```
def Computation(row):
    App = list(row['A']) # Will work as long as row['A'] is iterable

    # For the next 3 lines, see note below.
    PT = [row['B']] * len(App)
    CS = [row['C']] * len(App)
    DS = [row['D']] * len(App)

    File3 = tuplelist(zip(PT,CS,DS,App))
    return m.addConstr(quicksum(y[r,c,d,a] for r,c,d,a in File3) == 1)
```

Note: `[<list>] * n` will create `n` pointers or references to the same `<list>`, not `n` independent lists. Changes to one copy of `n` will change all copies in `n`. If that is not what you want, use a function. See [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python) for details. Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557558/3765319).