# what is the meaningin python of list=[none]*list size

Tags: python

```
""" https://www.interviewcake.com/question/python/merge-sorted-arrays """ 
import unittest 

def merge_sorted_arrays(first, second):     
    # setup our merged list    
    merged_list_size = len(first) + len(second)     
    merged_list = [None] * merged_list_size
```

What is the meaning of `merged_list=[None]*merged_list_size`? What does `[None]` stands for?

Comment: What happened when you ran that line of code?
What part don't you understand?

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557558/6699447) which explain this in detail. It clearly explains when you should use this, and when you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

This will create a list with `merged_list_size` number of None elements.

Say `merged_list_size` was 3...

```
>>> merged_list=[None]*3
>>> print merged_list
[None, None, None]
```

The result is a list with 3 elements all of the value None

edit:
when coming across things like this that you don't understand I would always test before looking for help. I personally always open a terminal and run the python command prompt to test out little things like this.

Comment: can you mark it as the correct answer so we can close the thread

Answer (score 0):

It does create a list of size `merged_list_size` whose elements are `None`. `None` is a built-in constant which represents the absence of a value.

Fore more info about built-in constants: https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html