# Create list by taking index o and repeating it based on index 1 value

Tags: python

My apology for this most inane question. I have very basic python knowledge, and I'm working on it. I need to create a simply list in python that would take a function call with two arguments `createList(v,n)`:

So that value would be a string say `e` and the next argument would be a number `5` and that would then create a list-

```
['e','e','e','e','e','e']
```

Conceptually I understand that e would be at index `0` and `5` would be at index 1, but I have no idea how to actually use the arguments to make the list.

I have searched to try and learn but there is nothing so simply as this. Again, my apology for the inane question, but I am trying!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49466525/edit) to include more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def createList(v,n):
    return [v] * n
```

- You use the arguments by simply referring to them by name :) .  No need to worry about which argument is first or second when you are inside `createList` — though they do need to be in the right order when you *call* `createList`.
- `[v]` makes a one-element list that contains `v`.
- `* n`, when applied to lists, expands that list to include `n` copies of what it had before.
- `return` returns the value from the function.

Comment: It says not to say thank you, but I am going to do so anyway, what simple syntax. I was conceptualizing things as far more complex. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MGinOttawa No worries :) .  Upvote/accept (checkmark) are the encouraged ways to say thanks, but I can't imagine anyone would object to a personal message :) .

Comment: @MGinOttawa And, as you are discovering, you can only hit the checkmark on one answer - preferably, the one that best helped you in your situation.  You can, however, upvote as many answers as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
def createList(v,n): 
    return [v for i in range(n)]
```

This solution is based on list comprehension.

Comment: This is a nice solution and again simple and elegant, thank you. I was thinking it would be more complicated such as find the value of index 0, then find the value of index 1 and create a loop that would go through and insert index 0 the number of times as index 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def createList(v,n):
    print([v for i in range(n)])
```

You can learn function and arguments in

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Comment: Again, a thank you despite being encouraged not to use comments for thanks, but manners matter.

Answer (score 0):

Slight improved answered of @cxw. Which will work for almost all the case except when `n = 0`.

```
def createList(v,n):
    return [v] * n if (n != 0) else [v]
```

Since if `n=0` the list `[v] * 0` would become empty `[]` list which I think wont be expected result in your case.