# Checking for key in dict during comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
d = {num: [num] if num not in d else d[num].append(num) for num in l}
```

Inherently, I wouldn't think so, without declaring `d = {}` first; even then, it doesn't append:

```
Output: {1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3], 4: [4]}
# desired: {1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3], 4: [4, 4]}
```

Could use a `defaultdict`, curious if the comprehension is even possible?

Comment: Nope not possible, use the `defaultdict`

Comment: if you have side effects within the comprehension, that's not functional style so I'd consider it a smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If you think about, it will make sense why. When Python evaluates an assignment statement, it first evaluates the right-hand side of the assignment - the expression. Since it hasn't evaluated the entire assignment yet, the variable on the left-hand hasn't been added to the current namespace yet. Thus, while the expression is being evaluated, the variable will be undefined.

As suggested, you can use `collections.defaultdict` to accomplish what you want:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for num in l:
        d[num].append(num)


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3], 4: [4, 4]})
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

d doesn't exist in your dictionary comprehension.
Why not:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
d = {num: [num] * l.count(num) for num in set(l)}
```

EDIT: I think, it is better to use a loop there

```
d = {}
for item in l:
    d.setdefault(item, []).append(item)
```

Comment: Yea I know it doesnt exist. When you declare `d = {}` prior, you get an overwritten (as I've shown) dict. It is unable to check for membership while iterating.

Comment: the `d` you declare before is not the same as the one you are building, so you will never use the else statement.

Comment: Sorry, using `l.count` for each iteration is *very* inefficient. It's a full pass each time. And you are doing all this many times (3 times for 1) which is unnecessary.

Comment: @jpp I know, the best answer is to do a real loop.

Comment: You can at-least cast the list `l` to `set` while iteration!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot refer to your list comprehension before the comprehension is assigned to a variable.

But you can use `collections.Counter` to limit those costly `list.append` calls.

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]

c = Counter(l)
d = {k: [k]*v for k, v in c.items()}

# {1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3], 4: [4, 4]}
```

Related: [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times-in-python)

Comment: This is radically different from your original answer (edited within the grace period), also why use a `Counter` over a `defaultdict`? This is exactly what `defaultdict` is for

Comment: To your first question, I actually *misread* the question, which is why I deleted it before updating (nothing sinister). To your second, this is a never-ending debate. One day, I'll write a Q&A explain all the benefits / disadvantages of each. In *this* instance, it's because I want to avoid repeated `list.append` calls.