# Generating list of a random word, random number of times

Tags: python, list, random

How do I generate a list that will contain only the type of monster randomly chosen in choice a random number of times (1-5)?

```
monsters = ("trolls", "ogres", "werewolves", "dragons")
choice = random.choice(monsters)
```

I have tried the following which delivers the number but how do I make a list out of it?

```
num = random.randint(1, 5)
print("Your hero must fight against: ", num, choice)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "the type of monster randomly chosen in choice a random number of times (1-5)" mean? Can you provide an example or two? Please read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3459098/354577)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand your questions, but I will answer it based on my understanding, please notify me if any mistakes.

Let's say you have a tuple of strings

```
monsters = ("trolls", "ogres", "werewolves", "dragons")
```

and you want to randomly pick random number of monsters from it, you can firstly generate a random number from the range by [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange), and then use list generator to construct the list

```py
nums = random.randint(1, 5) # nums = 2
monster_list = [random.choice(monsters) for i in range(nums)] 
# monster_list = ['ogres', 'trolls']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. It might be because you did not (correctly) import `random`

```
monsters = ("trolls", "ogres", "werewolves", "dragons")

choice = random.choice(monsters)
num = random.randint(1, 5)

print("Your hero must fight against: ", num, choice)
```