# How to make N copy of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list-A and I want to create another list-B which contains N copies of list-A

I tried below

```
list_b = [list_a for _ in range(n)]
#creates copies of the list

from itertools import repeat
list_b = [list_a for _ in repeat(None,n)]
#creates copies of the list
```

Is there any way to do this without creating a copy of list_a ?

Comment: `[list_a] * n`?

Comment: Dupe of [Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times), if you make the jump to the "single element" being a list and don't mind having references instead of copied values.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? The first example certainly doesn't make a copy of the list

Comment: Your current code creates no copies of `list_a` but builds a new list with a number of *references* to the original list. Just append an element to `list_a` and look at `list_b`... BTW the pythonic way would be `list_b = [list_a] * n`.

Comment: Guys, what are you even answering here? They are _not copies_. The list in the first example contains references to the same object in memory. It's not copied.

Answer (score 1):

easy peasy, thank you python

```
newList = [list_a]  * n
```

but please note that this copies the reference of original list `n` times and not copy the elements of the list

Comment: Add square brackets around `list_b` so that the list itself is copied, not its elements.

Comment: mark meyer, i am trying to do what OP is doing