# How to generate an array with the same element more directly?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have an array `value` of this form

```
array([0.69])
```

Then I would like to extract `0.69` to form an array of this form

```
array([[0.69],
       [0.69],
       [0.69],
       [0.69],
       [0.69],
       [0.69],
       [0.69]])
```

I feel that my code is very indirectly and requires many operations.

```
value = np.array([0.69])
np.array([[value[0].tolist()]] * 7)
```

Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal more directly?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times Seems like using `itertools.repeat()` is faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that `np.full((7, 1), value)` is faster and simpler than `np.array([[value[0].tolist()]] * 7)`.