# Simple way to create an incrementing Python array

Tags: python, arrays, list, initialization

I am wanting to initialize an array (in Python) that goes from 1 to some number `n`. I am wondering how I would do that in the simplest way...

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times#answer-24557558) answer, they share a way to initialize an array with all the same value, but I want to initialize mine to be more like this: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` if `n = 10`

I know I could do something like:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

arr = 0 * n

for (i in range(len(arr))):
    arr[i] = i+1
```

But I want it simpler... I'm sort of new to Python, so I don't know a whole lot. Would someone be able to show me how (and explain it or give a reference) to initialize an "incrementing array"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want it simpler

Make sure you understand [how `range` works and what it actually does](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). Since it is already [a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), and since it already contains the exact values you want, all you need to do in order to get a list is to convert the type, by creating a list from the range.

It looks like:

```
list(range(n))
```

Yep, that's it.

Comment: Notice that the documentation does this same thing in multiple examples, specifically to show what numbers the example `range`s contain. `print`ing a `range` directly is possible, but what it gives you is not especially useful unless you already understand.

Comment: `list(range(1,n+1))`

Comment: True, but it's better to get used to the idea of starting to count from 0 :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - That is a _very_ simple solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Based on Karl's answer, you should have something like this :

```
arr = list(range(1, n+1))
print(arr)
```

=======================================================
I'm not really sure about your question. but let me try

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
arr = []
for i in range (1,n+1):
    arr.append(i)
print(arr)
```

use `append` to add any item to the tail of the array.