# How to return literal text strings to be used in another function

Tags: python, string, class

I am learning how the classes work, but I have encountered a problem that had appeared to me on other occasions.

The question is that I want to have a class to which two parameters are passed: columns and rows. And that by calling a method inside the class, that table is automatically generated.

```
class Tables:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

    def generate_T(self):
        table = BeautifulTable()
        for i in range(self.rows):
            table.rows.append([""])
        
            
        print(table)
```

The `table.rows.append` method requires that for each column this is inserted: `"",`. I try this:

```
columns = "\"\","*self.columns
for i in range(self.rows):
    table.rows.append([columns[:-1])
```

It does not work, since it is taken as a single text string, I have also tried to remove the comma from the function, but then some parentheses appear.
Is there any method to fix this?
Greetings and thanks

P.D: To be clear: `table.rows.append (["", "", ""])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create list of single item repeated N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times). Basically, you want `table.rows.append([""] * self.columns)`.

Comment: That work's perfect. Thanks

Comment: But I don't undestarnd how it works. Why It doesn't return `["]["]["]...`?

Comment: Because it is a list and not a string. Conversely, in your question, you used a string when you should have used a list.